# Flutter Doctor; command not found

Tags: flutter, installation

Installing flutter using documentation for macOS. I entered the commands below:

$ `unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_v1.9.1+hotfix.6-stable.zip`

$ `export PATH="$PATH:'pwd'/flutter/bin"`

and then try

$ `flutter doctor` , as instructed and get command not found

(also got command not found when trying '`flutter precache`')

Comment: have you set this path `export PATH="/Users/skara/development/flutter/bin:$PATH"` in **.bash_profile**

Comment: Yes, still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

then

```
export PATH="$PATH:/yourpath_to_/flutter/bin"
```

after that save doc 
pres <kbd>esc</kbd> +<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>

after that

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line and change "pwd" :

```
 export PATH="$PATH:'pwd'/flutter/bin"
```

to be the path where you cloned Flutter’s git repo